# Reinstalling Windows with some partitions on bitlocker encryption

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I need to fully reinstall a Windows 7 on a laptop. Problem is the other partition is encrypted on Bitlocker I'm kinda worried that it may no longer be accessible after i reformat the main partition and install Windows 7.

Is it safe to do a reformat+reinstall on this machine?
Or should I removed the bitlocker encryption first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to read a bitlocker volume is independent of the OS, as long as the OS is bitlocker capable.  Once you install Windows 7 again, you will be able to access the bitlocker  encrypted partition as you did before.  Check out the [FAQ](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_AltPC) from MS.